# How to store an object in to a variable

Tags: java

I am a beginner in JAVA and I could use some help. So I have 3 classes : Client,BankAccount and Test. I need to add into a Client object the details from a BankAccount. This is the code:

```
public class Client {
    private String name;
    private String adress;
    private BankAccount accounts[];

    public Client(String name,String adress,BankAccount accounts){
        this.name=name;
        this.adress=adress;
        this.accounts=accounts;

    }

public class BankAccount {
    private String numarCont;
    private float suma;

    public ContBancar(String accNumber,float sum){
        this.accNumber=accNumber;
        this.sum=sum;
    }

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Bankaccount b=new Bankaccount("f211s1",200);
            Bankaccount b1=new Bankaccount("f23131EUR",5000);
            System.out.println(b);
            Client c=new Client("John","142VineYard",b);
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
```

A client can have multiple accounts. The problem is that I don't know how can I add the details of object b into object c.

Comment: Have you translated this code from another language? The constructor in `BankAccount` is incorrect.

Comment: Do not add the details of `b` in c`. Add `b` to `c`

Comment: The field `accounts` is of type `BankAccount[]`, not of type `BankAccount`. To make that clear, and reduce your confusion, it should be declared as `private BankAccount[] accounts;`

Comment: Your code has lots of errors! Fix them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a List for your BankAccounts

```
public class Client {
    private String name;
    private String adress;
    private List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

    public Client(String name,String adress,BankAccount account){
        this.name=name;
        this.adress=adress;
        this.accounts.add(account);
    }

    public void addBankAccount(BBankAccount account){
        this.accounts.add(account);
    }
}
```

This way it is a easier to add Accounts.

```
c.addBankAccount(b);
c.addBankAccount(b1);
```

Maybe it would help you to take a look at some basic [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is inheritance. Inheritance will allow you to use the methods of one class in another class as if it was the same object. The keyword for inheriting in Java is extends used like this:

```
Public class foo extends foobar
```